# Beanstalkd Listen Address Issue on AWS EC2

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, beanstalkd

I installed beanstalkd on AWS EC2 and it was working perfectly fine on local server. But now, i need to change the listen address to my public IP of EC2 instance so that i can push jobs from remote server

> BEANSTALKD_LISTEN_ADDR=127.0.0.1

But when i change it to the public IP of my EC2 instance, beanstalkd can't restart. Is there any way i can look for logs of beanstalkd.

Please help, how i can change the address so that i can push jobs from remote.

Thanks

Comment: `BEANSTALKD_LISTEN_ADDR=0.0.0.0`?

Comment: What are the rules in the EC2 security group?

Comment: this is security group for aws. 
All All 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: BEANSTALKD_LISTEN_ADDR=0.0.0.0 works for me. Can you please put this as answer so that i can mark it. And please let me know if this thing will have any security issues.